# change custom product tab position in admin grid Magento

Tags: magento, tabs, position, admin, product

Hi i have added a new product tab in admin grid by following the below link

http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-custom-product-relations-in-magento/

Everything is working fine. BUt this has added the new tab at the last position in product edit section. Can you please suggest me how can i change the position of that tab.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the action `addTabAfter` instead of `addTab`, then you have to specify the `<after>` parameter (categories, websites, upsell...).

I edited the code of your tutorial for example:

```
<reference name="product_tabs">
    <action method="addTabAfter">
        <name>custom</name>
        <block>inchoo_customlinkedproducts/adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_tab</block>
        <after>upsell</after>
    </action>
</reference>
```

I hope this is fexible enough for you.

Comment: There's something odd happening on mine.  One extension in *local* had a tab on customer edit that appeared at the bottom, but they hadn't done anything special.  Mine (also *local*) appeared just under Customer View.  I changed my Layout XML to use *addTabAfter* and it caused the other extension's tab to move up to position 2 and mine is now at position 3.  This seems like there's no rhyme or reason to the order unless you specify *after* on all tabs.

Answer (score 0):

after searching a lot i have not got any default solution to change the custom tab position so i have decided to go with JavaScript.

I manage to do this with the below code

**in my module file i have loaded a custom JavaScript file with the below code on product edit action and product create action**

```
  <adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
    <reference name="head">
      <action method="addJs">
        <script>jsoveride/accesorytab.js</script>
      </action>
    </reference>
  </adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
  <adminhtml_catalog_product_new>
    <reference name="head">
      <action method="addJs">
        <script>jsoveride/accesorytab.js</script>
      </action>
    </reference>
  </adminhtml_catalog_product_new>
```

**and in the i have use the below code**

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
document.getElementById("product_info_tabs_crosssell").appendChild(document.getElementById("product_info_tabs_custom"));      
        });
```

and it has done my work.

If anybody gets better solution please let me know.

thanks