# Magento tab order in admin customer edit

Tags: magento

With the following code, the 'myinfo' tab is added tie the customer edit page, but it appears a second element after the 'customer view'.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <adminhtml_customer_edit>
        <reference name="left">
            <reference name="customer_edit_tabs">
                <block type="mystuff/adminhtml_customer_edit_tab_myinfo" name="tab_points"
                       template="my/stuff/customer/myinfo.phtml">
                    ...
                </block>
                <action method="addTab">
                    <name>my_stuff</name>
                    <block>tab_myinfo</block>
                    <!-- TODO find way to change sequence of tab added -->
                </action>
            </reference>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_customer_edit>
</layout>
```

*...I'd like to add a screenshot... but my reputation is too low :(*

How can the sequence of appearance be defined? I tried the following:

```
1. <action method="addTab" after="cart">
       ...

2. <action method="addTab">
       <after>cart</after>
       ...

3.  <action method="addTab">
       <sequence>999</sequence>
       ...
```

... but no change

Comment: check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30521418/change-custom-product-tab-position-in-admin-grid-magento

Comment: @adrien54 Thanks. Works as expected.